# Using Jquery methods on Data Returned from Ajax, with out printing out the data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I have a rather unique situation. I am using JQuery to gather some data based on two date ranges, what is returned as a response in the `$data` variable (I am using Ajax) I have set, is a html table.

Now I don't want the user to ever see this table, I want to use [This jquery plugin](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html) to download the CSV file of that table. The question is, if the table sits inside of a `$data` and can be seen via the network tab in Chrom Dev Tools, under Response, is it possible to be manipulated with Jquery?

In our inhouse framework, we do the following to get Ajax Data:

```
    // The following belongs to a JS class method.
    data = {
        startDate : $('.startDate').val(),
        endDate : $('.endDate').val()
    }

    CT.postSynch('report/payRollReport/downloadPayRoleReport', {data : data}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
```

We pass a data object to our Ajax wrapper, call a controller with an action (in this case `downloadPayRoleReport` translates to `ajaxDownloadPayRoleReport()`) which in turn returns an HTML table, which I can view via `console.log(data)`

I want to use the above linked plugin on `data` to then turn this html table into a csv and instant download.

Question is, can this be done?

Comment: Please see linked plugin for further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a jQuery object from the table.  Then you can do anything to the jQuery object just like you could if it were actually on the DOM.  You can always put the table on the DOM as well off screen, but I think any chance you have to not touch the DOM you should take it.

```
var myTable = $(data);

myTable.mySpecialTableMethodToExportToCSV();
```

Comment: NP.  I can't tell you how long I went without this little insight.  Comes in very handy.  Enjoy.  :)